# Show labels for minor ticks also

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

In `matplotlib`, when I use a `log` scale on one axis, it might happen that that axis will have **no major ticks**, **only minor** ones. So this means **no labels** are shown for the whole axis.

How can I specify that I need labels also for minor ticks?

I tried:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=True)
```

... but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: never mind my close vote, greatly mis-read the question.  If you have no major log ticks on your graph, you probably should not be using a log scale.

Comment: @tcaswell that's not true: if you have a function that is close to power law (possibly with some small feature), you want to use a log scale also with small ranges. Then in a log plot major ticks are in power of 10 so you can have a range [2000, 9000] and no major ticks

Comment: That's what I thought. I can have thousands of points all concentrated (with very little scatter) around one value not close to any power of 10 and still want to apply a log scale to the X axis.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano The range [2000, 9000] is less than a decade, I would a priori be skeptical of any power law claims based on that range of data.  Put another way, if you have less than a decade of data, what are you gaining by using a log scale?

Comment: @tcaswell: I'm not talking about any power law claims (I used the power law as example of something that you want probably to plot in log scale). I'm just saying that there are cases where you want to make a log plot with a relatively small range and can happen that you have one or no major tick. In both cases would be nice to have some minor tick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tried many ways to get minor ticks working properly in log plots. If you are fine with showing the log of the value of the tick you can use [`matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterExponent`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatterExponent). I remember trying [`matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter) but I didn't like it much: if I remember well it puts everything in `base^exp` (also 0.1, 0, 1). In both cases (as well as all the other `matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter*`) you have to set `labelOnlyBase=False` to get minor ticks.

I ended up creating a custom function and use [`matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter). My approach assumes that the ticks are at integer values and that you want a base 10 log.

```
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

def ticks_format(value, index):
    """
    get the value and returns the value as:
       integer: [0,99]
       1 digit float: [0.1, 0.99]
       n*10^m: otherwise
    To have all the number of the same size they are all returned as latex strings
    """
    exp = np.floor(np.log10(value))
    base = value/10**exp
    if exp == 0 or exp == 1:   
        return '${0:d}$'.format(int(value))
    if exp == -1:
        return '${0:.1f}$'.format(value)
    else:
        return '${0:d}\\times10^{{{1:d}}}$'.format(int(base), int(exp))

subs = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 6.0]  # ticks to show per decade
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=subs)) #set the ticks position
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())   # remove the major ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(ticks_format))  #add the custom ticks
#same for ax.yaxis
```

If you don't remove the major ticks and use `subs = [2.0, 3.0, 6.0]` the font size of the major and minor ticks is different (this *might* be cause by using `text.usetex:False` in my `matplotlibrc`)

Comment: This function is a brilliant approach to getting good formatting for logarithmic tick-mark labels! Great post!

Answer (score 19):

You can use `set_minor_tickformatter` on the corresponding axis:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

axes = plt.subplot(111)
axes.loglog([3,4,7], [2,3,4])
axes.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
plt.xlim(1.8, 9.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it is worth mentioning the option "minor_thresholds" introduced in matplotlib version 2.0 ([docs link](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogFormatter)). It's a parameter in the form of a pair (subset, all) of the class LogFormatter that allows you to specify when a (fixed) subset of minor ticklabels should be shown and when all minor ticklabels should be shown (explanation of what this means is at the bottom).

In the following code I show the effect by using the same parameter values ((2, 0.4) in this case) but changing the limits of the x-axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatter
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, figsize=(12, 24))

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(dt, 20.0, dt)

# first plot doesn't use a formatter
axes[0].semilogx(t, np.exp(-t / 5.0))
axes[0].set_xlim([0, 25])
axes[0].grid()

xlims = [[0, 25], [0.2, 8], [0.6, 0.9]]

for ax, xlim in zip(axes[1:], xlims):
    ax.semilogx(t, np.exp(-t / 5.0))
    formatter = LogFormatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(2, 0.4))
    ax.get_xaxis().set_minor_formatter(formatter)
    ax.set_xlim(xlim)
    ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:
[image]

You see that in the **second row** the ticklabels are the same as in the first row where we didn't use a formatter. This is because the log of the view-range is more than 2 (the first value of the parameter pair) or to put it differently, the view spans a range that is bigger than a range between two major ticklabels. In the **third row** the view is smaller than 2 but bigger than 0.4 (the second value of the parameter pair), so we see a **subset** of the minor ticklabels. Finally, in the **last row** the view spans less than 0.4 of the space between two major ticklabels, so **all** minor ticklabels are shown.