# matplotlib how to plot semilog graph with yticks and horizontal grid lines spaced logarithmically

Tags: python, logging, matplotlib, plot, python-2.5

I want to plot some y data in range 20000 to 50000.

I want the y axis to go from 10000 to 60000 in steps of 5000.
I want the y axis to be a log plot.

I tried `ax1.set_yscale('log')`. This gave a log plot but no horizontal grid lines and no y ticks.

How do I get grid lines in both directions and y ticks going up 10000, 15000 etc., with a log spacing?

I am trying to get a yaxis scale like this

[image]

I'm using the following code in Python 2.5.2:

```
fig = pl.figure()
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 10 # set graph size
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(do,line,'r-', do,ind,'g-')  
ax1.grid(True)
pl.xticks(do,rotation=45)
ax1.set_xlim( [date1, date2] )
ax1.set_yscale('log')
pl.show()
```

I could calculate `log(line)` and `log(ind)` and do a linear plot but the graph would not be as informative!

Comment: The image isn't viewable when I click on the link. Can you just put it on here directly instead of a link?

Comment: Check out the examples in the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/log_demo.html)

Comment: hmmm ........... yes the link isnt clickable! I had to copy and paste it - sorry

Comment: I've looked at the gallery the examples use numbers going up in powers of 10 eg 10 to 10000. They dont use numbers in smaller ranges like 10 to 60

Comment: This a similar graph; hopefully clickable         http://bigcharts.marketwatch.com/kaavio.Webhost/charts/big.chart?nosettings=1&symb=mu&uf=0&type=128&size=2&sid=3145&style=320&freq=1&entitlementtoken=0c33378313484ba9b46b8e24ded87dd6&time=9&rand=683429634&compidx=aaaaa%3a0&ma=0&maval=9&lf=1&lf2=0&lf3=0&height=335&width=579&mocktick=1

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to turn the minor grid on.  But also be aware that a range from 10 to 60 is quite small for a logarithmic plot (which is why the major grid doesn't appear)

```
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()
# rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 10 # set graph size
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
#ax1.plot(line,'r-', ind,'g-')
ax1.grid(True)
# pl.xticks(do,rotation=45)
ax1.set_xlim([10, 20])
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_ylim([10000, 60000])
ax1.grid(which='minor')
pl.show()
```

Comment: In the light of your comments, this may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209836/4735642

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the interest. After reading your suggestions and Beachcombers link and some experimentation, I came up with the following solution.

```
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 10 # set graph size
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(do,line,'r-', do, ind,'g-')
ax1.grid(True)
pl.xticks(do,rotation=45)
ax1.set_xlim( [date1, date2] )
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.grid(which='minor')
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.0f"))
pl.show()
```