# How to add minor ticks between two minors ticks in log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show grids between two minors ticks in log scale, is there a way to do that?
for exp: between 1 and 10 there is 10 grids, I want 10 grids 1 and 2 too
and the same between 10 and 20, same for 100 et 200 and the rest.

Here's a pic to explain a little bit what I want

[image: pic1]

The one on the right is what I did so far, the one on the left is what I want.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't even start, if it linear scale it will be done just by using yticks and multipleLocator, but in log scale the scale doubles each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib semi-log plot: minor tick marks are gone when range is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078409/matplotlib-semi-log-plot-minor-tick-marks-are-gone-when-range-is-large)

Comment: nop, not that, he wanted to show minors ticks when the range is large, in my case, there is minors ticks, but in want another minors ticks brtween every two minors ticks, I don't know how to explain it, it' like a minor minor ticks (double).

Comment: I guess it would help then if you can spend more than 2 sentences on the problem. Also maybe a drawing would help?

Comment: Why don't you try to do it yourself, and then edit your question with your code when you get stuck.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I uploaded a pic now, I think you can understand me now.