# Matplotlib add gridlines not working as expected

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, subplot, gridlines

Using matplotlib `subplots()` in Jupyter Notebook, and using "seaborn-whitegrid" `plot.style()`.

I am trying to add minor gridlines to my x-axis, which is in log.

What am I missing?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

x, y = [(1, 9, 65, 142, 330), (0, 0.16, 0.50, 0.84, 1)]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,5, figsize=(8.5,5.5), constrained_layout=True)

#counter = 0
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.set_title('Dataset-A', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel('CFD', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_xlim([1, 1000])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.grid(True, axis='both', which='minor', color='red')

    #counter += 1 ##will use to iterate through real dataset
```

[image]

Comment: When running your code verbatim, I see gridlines as well as as different x-axis with 10 to the ) to 10 to the4 3. What version are you on?

Comment: @DavidErickson even with `plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')`?

Comment: yes, I am seeing a different image than what you are showing. `'0.11.1'` is my seaborn version. `'3.1.3'` is my `matplotlib` version. You can use `sns.__version__` and `matplotlib.__version__`. Make sure to do just `import matplotlib`. What is your version?

Comment: wow, any idea why that would happen?  I just shut down notebook, restarted, started new notebook and I see same plot as I show above

Comment: Similar to David not reproducible here. Does the same happen in your environment outside Jupyter Notebook or not? Most likely some setting there that causes this behavior.

Comment: @Mr.T yes, it does happen outside Notebook in this environment. I also tried it in the default Anaconda environment and it happens there too. Both are Python 3x. I ran it in a Python 2.7 (install not from Anaconda) and it worked correctly. Bummer, the environment-based problem seems tougher to fix. Thanks all for the independent tests

Comment: Well this is an annoying solution, but it works: `y_minor = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base = 10.0, subs = np.arange(1.0, 10.0) * 0.1, numticks = 10)` ... `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(y_minor)` ... `ax.grid(True, axis='x', which='minor', color='red')` ... from 2nd answer by user "zyy" here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887920/how-to-show-minor-tick-labels-on-log-scale-with-matplotlib