# How to set the axis scale and ticklabels using matplotlib object oriented API

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I would need some help with plotting in Matplotlib.pyplot under Python2.7!

I want to generate a plot with the following x-axis:

[x-axis as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcosX.jpg)

I got so far by using `myaxis.set_xticks([0,0.5,1,2,4,6,8])` and it looks good, but if I want to create **an logarithmic x-axis* **, then my axis labels look like this!

[wrong x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGtse.jpg)

What can I do to have both a log-scaled x-axis and integer formated labels (not logarithmic values as labels either!). **Please read the note regarding to the log-scale!!!**

While browsing Stackoverflow I found the following similar question, but nothing of the suggestions worked for me and I do not know what I did wrong.

[Matplotlib: show labels for minor ticks also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165435/matplotlib-show-labels-for-minor-ticks-also)

Thanks!

**Note:** This plot is called **Madau-Plot** (*see:adsabs[dot]harvard[dot]edu Madau (1998) DOI=10.1086/305523*). It is common to plot it log-scales and show the z=0.0 value although the axis is log-scaled axis and `log10(0)=Error`. I definitely want to point out here that this is common use in my field but should not be applied one to one to any other plots. **So actually the plot is made with a trick! You plot (1+z) [1,1.5,2,3,5,7,9]] and then translate the x-axis to the pure z-values 0.0 < z 8.0!** So what I need to find is how to set xticks to the "translated" values ([0,0.5,1,2,4,6,8])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you plotted your datapoint corresponding to x=0 somewhere else, like at x=0.25, then relabel it.  For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plot_vals = [0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
label_vals = [0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]

ax.plot(plot_vals, plot_vals, 'k-o')

ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(plot_vals) 
ax.set_xticklabels(label_vals) # relabeling the ticklabels
```

This yields what I think is what you want.

[image]

You can turn off minor ticks by doing something like:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', bottom='off', top='off')
```

---

**Edit:** Given the edit to the op, this can be done easily by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


original_values = [0, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]

# if using numpy:
# import numpy as np
# plot_values = np.array(original_values) + 1

# if using pure python
plot_values = [i + 1 for i in original_values]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(plot_values, plot_values, 'k-o') #substitute actual plotting here
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(plot_values)
ax.set_xticklabels(original_values)
```

which yields:

[image]