# Matplotlib pyplot Log-scale axis tick mark labels (values) dissapear. How to set tick marks and labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

When creating an y-axis log-scale the plot displays some tick marks but no labels for these tick marks. How can someone:

1. Make the labels of the default tick mark position re-appear
2. Change the position of the tick marks and therefore their label values

I am plotting these two arrays:

```
E=[0.0e+00 9.0e+16 1.8e+17 2.7e+17 3.6e+17 4.5e+17 5.4e+17 6.3e+17 7.2e+17
 8.1e+17 9.0e+17]

m=[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
```

using this Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
fig=plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()


plt.plot(m,E,'r',linewidth=4)
plt.xlim([1, 10])
plt.ylim([E[1], max(E)])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
#ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LogLocator())
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Comment: hi! No i am excluding this value from the plot i get the second point onwards plt.xlim([1, 10])
plt.ylim([E[1], max(E)])

Comment: According to the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674522/12046409) you can use `ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.LogFormatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(2, 0.4)))`.  A problem is that with your ylims only 1 major tick is visible.

Comment: thank you I just show your reply after I figured it out. This works as well thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a work around. So this is what I used to get:

[image]

Basically you can see a lot of minor tick marks but only one major and only this single major has a label. So I removed this single major tick-mark and its label and then added labels to the minor tick marks and I got exactly what I wanted.

Someone could try and actually specify the major tickmarks instead and remove the minor ones BUT this solution works for me  and it my be an easy quick fix for someone else.

The final code displays the tick amrk labels in scientific notation. The code and the graph are:
fig=plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

```
plt.plot(m,E,'r',linewidth=4)
plt.xlim([5, 10])
plt.ylim([E[5], max(E)])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.title('E=m$c^2$')
plt.xlabel('Mass (grams)')
plt.ylabel('Energy (joules)')

#This makes the major tick mark hidde
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())

#This sets the minor tickmarks labels to display in scientific notation
#ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(plt.FormatStrFormatter("%.0E"))

formatter = plt.LogFormatter(labelOnlyBase=False, minor_thresholds=(1,0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Removing your only major tick is really weird.  Something else, please [never post code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: i changed the code from picture to text, but I dont think it is weird at all if the major tick marks are so far apart and the minor tickmarrks are perfectly log spaced what is weird about using that scale? It works, it is correct, it looks good. Anyway it looks good to me at least, so someone else might also find it usefull.